# Inserting a date into cell or box to change chart data range

Tags: excel, vba, range, excel-charts

I keep an Excel sheet of my weather station data to help calculate the days between spraying. I've then made a dial to quickly show me when my next day is due based up the GP numbers. I use a simple =sum (cell F8) to keep a running tally over the week.

Is it possible to create an input box that will allow me to enter the date I sprayed that would reset the data range from that specific day? To recognise the date in column A and use the data in column B. The dial usually sits on a dashboard on a separate sheet.

[image]

Comment: Maybe just INDEX and MATCH is all you need, instead of VBA.

Comment: That would be a lot easier. I'll give it a try.